# Update META tag value from JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a web page that is using the following META tag:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="15;URL=/myPage.aspx" />
```

This page has a textbox and a drop down list. When the user changes either of these fields, I am hitting a web service via JQuery. I would like to append the values of these fields as query string values to the URL in the META tag shown above. Is there a way to do this from JQuery? If so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: I doubt updating that tag would have the effect you want, though I could be wrong. Why don't you just navigate to the next page after the time expires, instead?

Comment: what do you mean by next page? I'm trying to simply refresh the page in the event that new data has been added. The purpose of the input fields is to serve as filters. I want to take those filters into account when the page refreshes.

Comment: You could refresh the page in javascript/jquery. window.location.href = window.location.href or window.location.reload()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");` to redirect, and `setTimeout()` if you need to set a timer.